# Android Webview Titanium trying to post something on hyves.nl

Tags: android, post, webview, titanium

I'm trying to post something on the social network site hyves.nl

The following works on a browser:

```
http://www.hyves.nl/hyvesconnect/smartbutton/?type=11&title=title&body=body&category=12&rating=5
```

but when I try to invoke it from a webview in android, I cannot login. I enter my credentials and it reloads the same login screen again when I click login. This happens when I pass the above url. If I pass only http://www.hyves.nl then I can login and it saves my logined status.
So what can be wrong and cannot save my login status when trying to pass the above parameters?

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: when i run your url in my browser it's not logged in. It's asking me for username and password

Comment: Hyves is a social network like facebook. you have to login. If you login, it will post the parameters passing. The problem is that this does not work from a browser in android. I try to login and it reloads the initial login window instead of posting the passing data to my logined profile.

Comment: I assume thats a flaw in the Hyves site. Use their API: http://hyves-api.hyves.nl/